# How to display site title with post title?

Tags: wp-admin

Is it possible to have the site title prepended before each post title, separated by a hyphen?  For example:

```
[my site title] - [my post title]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function prepend_site_name($title) {
  return get_bloginfo('name').' - '.$title;
}
add_filter('the_title','prepend_site_name');
```

Like that?

Comment: Ok, thanks.  If it can't be done in the WP admin, I'll need to see how this translates into Thesis 2's non PHP platform.

Comment: If you don't mind using a plugin, you could install [Yoast SEO plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/). This will also add a ton of other SEO features you might not want, so before you install please inform yourself on this plugin. If you do decide to use this plugin anyway: Just enter your desired settings under "SEO >> titels & meta's" In your case: > %%sitename%% - %%title%%

Comment: Given that Yoast SEO simply filters `the_title`, using the method described in the accepted answer, this really doesn't provide a different answer, and would probably be better as an edit or comment to the accepted answer.